# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime from SQLite file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a program, that puts the .txt files to a database file (im using system.data.sqlite NuGET package). I have yyyy.MM.dd format set on my Pc, and it's used by the database too, however I still get the above mentioned error.

An additional info, that could help, is that when I set the table's appropriate column to a simple string it's working as normal, but as soon As I set it to date it gives me this exeption.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You have, probably, *hardcoded* query, like `"select ... where ... SomeField = " + MyDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")+ "`; try use *parametrized* query instead: `"select ... where SomeField = @SomeField"` and the create query parameter with `MyDate` value

Comment: Nope, this does the error when I do simple stuff, like SELECT * FROM (insert table name here)

Comment: could you provide the relevant code, please?

Comment: Sure, here are pictures of code: https://imgur.com/a/ss8ursl

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up how a type is formatted into text with the type itself. If a column is typed as date, then its expecting a *date*, not a text conforming to whatever date format you have in mind.

Its the same is if you try to do the following:

```
DateTime date = "01.01.2020";
```

This won't compile, because `string`, nevermind if it represents a valid formatted date, and `DateTime` are two altogether different types.

If you are reading from a text file, you first need to convert the formatted string representations to their corresponding `DateTime`. See [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method on how to do this. Once you have valid dates in your hands, try pushing those to the DB.

Comment: This didnt' work sadly, https://imgur.com/a/ss8ursl I've tried parsing it, but to no avail.